# Moderator tools design issues and inconsistencies

Tags: bug, design

I've noticed some design bugs and inconsistencies in the 10k moderator tools pages.

The [`/tools/new-answers-old-questions`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) page overflows its container:

> [image]

The [`/tools/suggested-edits`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits) page counter butts the top of the sidebar:

> [image]

A better example of a similar counter can be seen on the [`/tools/post-feedback`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) page:

> [image]

The "New Answer to Old Questions" and "Suggested Edits" pages should probably have a solid white full-width container encompassing the title and navigation links as all the other pages do too, as you can see in the previous and following screenshot:

> [image]

Add to the list the [new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287081/307988), [`tools/protected-questions`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions) page, which also breaks out of its container, and could do with some work on the spacing, especially on the table headers:

> [image]

The footer width also extends further than it should (it looks like the container `<div>` is actually the correct width but the navigation blocks have an explicit width set too wide—correcting it doesn't seem to have any adverse effects).

Note, the footer width isn't limited to the moderator tools but is more noticeable there because of the full width container (most of the site has a sidebar that doesn't usually reach as low as the content container).

> [image]

Comment: It is certainly true that our mod pages have seen less love than the rest of the site - and I do find it immensely appropriate that this would be flagged as an issue on [graphicdesign.se]; I'll see if I can spend some cycles on it

Comment: Maybe this post should be moved to MSE site?

Comment: @alexolut a lot of this is limited to GDSE and could be fixed with changes to the site-specific CSS and I don't have 10k anywhere else to know what is and isn't site specific... And the powers that be will see this just as well here anyway :)